# Google Cloud Messaging: don't receive alerts when iOS App is in background

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, google-cloud-messaging

I have followed this tutorial https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client to implement GCM on my iOS Application. My app server is a google app engine written in Java and I use the gcm-server.jar https://github.com/google/gcm library. I think my certificates are fine and I can register, get a token and even receive the content of the messages sent by my app server. However, I don't receive any notification alerts when the app is in background, I always receive it only when I click on the app icon to restart it.

I thought that was because I was only implementing `didReceiveRemoteNotification:` and not `didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` so I implemented it instead of the first one but I don't receive notifications while in background either and worse, the app crashes saying something like"unrecognized selector sent to instance didReceiveRemoteNotification:" like something was wrong in the userInfo. I did allow background modes in xCode like required for it. Here is the code I use:

```
AppDelegate ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *registrationOptions;
@property (nonatomic, strong) GGLInstanceIDTokenHandler registrationHandler;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

//-- Set Notification
[[GCMService sharedInstance] startWithConfig:[GCMConfig defaultConfig]];
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)])
{
    NSLog(@"Case iOS8");
    // iOS 8 Notifications
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Case iOS7");
    // iOS < 8 Notifications
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
}

self.registrationHandler = ^(NSString *registrationToken, NSError *error){
    if (registrationToken != nil) {

        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setObject:registrationToken forKey:TOKENGCM];
        NSLog(@"Registration Token: %@", registrationToken);
        //some code
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Registration to GCM failed with error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
};
return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
[[GCMService sharedInstance] disconnect];
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
// Connect to the GCM server to receive non-APNS notifications
[[GCMService sharedInstance] connectWithHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Could not connect to GCM: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Connected to GCM");
        // ...
    }
}];
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
}


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
// Start the GGLInstanceID shared instance with the default config and request a registration
// token to enable reception of notifications
[[GGLInstanceID sharedInstance] startWithConfig:[GGLInstanceIDConfig defaultConfig]];
self.registrationOptions = @{kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption:deviceToken,
                         kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:@NO};
[[GGLInstanceID sharedInstance] tokenWithAuthorizedEntity:SENDER_ID
                                                    scope:kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM
                                                  options:self.registrationOptions
                                                  handler:self.registrationHandler];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err {
NSLog(@"Error in registration. Error: %@", err);
}

- (void)onTokenRefresh {
// A rotation of the registration tokens is happening, so the app needs to request a new token.
NSLog(@"The GCM registration token needs to be changed.");
[[GGLInstanceID sharedInstance] tokenWithAuthorizedEntity:SENDER_ID
                                                    scope:kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM
                                                  options:self.registrationOptions
                                                  handler:self.registrationHandler];
}


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
NSLog(@"Notification received: %@", userInfo);//This does print the content of my message in the console if the app is in foreground
UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
if (state == UIApplicationStateActive) {
    NSString *cancelTitle = @"Close";
    NSString *showTitle = @"Show";
    NSString *message = [[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"alert"];
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Some title"
                                                        message:message
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:cancelTitle
                                              otherButtonTitles:showTitle, nil];
    [alertView show];
}
else{
    NSLog(@"Notification received while inactive");
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 99];
    UIAlertView *BOOM = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"BOOM"
                                                   message:@"app was INACTIVE"
                                                  delegate:self
                                         cancelButtonTitle:@"a-ha!"
                                         otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [BOOM show];
    NSLog(@"App was NOT ACTIVE");
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Notification!"
                                                        object:nil
                                                      userInfo:userInfo];
}
// This works only if the app started the GCM service
[[GCMService sharedInstance] appDidReceiveMessage:userInfo];
}

//Implement that causes unrecognized selector crash 
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))handler {
NSLog(@"Notification received: %@", userInfo);
// This works only if the app started the GCM service
[[GCMService sharedInstance] appDidReceiveMessage:userInfo];
// Handle the received message
// Invoke the completion handler passing the appropriate UIBackgroundFetchResult value
// [START_EXCLUDE]
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"notif"
                                                    object:nil
                                                  userInfo:userInfo];
handler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
// [END_EXCLUDE]
}

@end
```

Can someone figure out what I don't receive notifications when not in foreground?

**EDIT**: the Java code used on the server side to send the GCM message:

```
public static MulticastResult sendViaGCM(String tag, String message, List<String> deviceIdsList) throws IOException {
    Sender sender = new Sender(Constantes.API_KEY);
    // This message object is a Google Cloud Messaging object
    Message msg = new Message.Builder().addData("tag",tag).addData("message", message).build();
    MulticastResult result = sender.send(msg, deviceIdsList, 5);
    return result;
}
```

**EDIT2:** screenshots of the POST Request 
http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/34/1440193492-gcm1.png
http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/34/1440193502-gcm2.png

**EDIT3:** the request I now send from my app server:

```
public static void sendGCMMessage(String tag, String message, List<String> deviceIdsList) {
    String request = "https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send";
    try{
        URL url = new URL(request);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        //conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        //Les deux headers obligatoires:
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=" + API_KEY);
        //Construction du JSON:
        JSONObject fullJSON = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject data=new JSONObject();
        JSONObject notification=new JSONObject();
        data.put("tag", tag);
        data.put("message", message);
        notification.put("sound", "default");
        notification.put("badge", "1");
        notification.put("title", "default");
        notification.put("body", message);
        fullJSON.put("registration_ids", deviceIdsList);

        fullJSON.put("notification", notification);
        fullJSON.put("content_available", "true");
        fullJSON.put("data", data);

        //Phase finale:
        OutputStreamWriter wr= new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(fullJSON.toString());
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();//pas obligatoire
        //conn.setUseCaches(false);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based on the [GCM documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server-ref#send-downstream), you can set the `content_available` to `true`.

(*On iOS, use this field to represent content-available in the APNS payload. When a notification or message is sent and this is set to true, an inactive client app is awoken. On Android, data messages wake the app by default. On Chrome, currently not supported.*)

The `content_available` is correspond to Apple's `content-available`, which you can find in [this Apple Push Notification Service documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html).

Also, you should use [Notification playload](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server-ref#notification-payload-support), for sending message to your iOS application, so that it can show a banner when your app is in background.

Here's a sample HTTP request:

```
https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=API_KEY
{
   "to" : "REGISTRATION_TOKEN",
   "notification" : {
     "sound" : "default",
     "badge" : "1",
     "title" : "default",
     "body"  : "Test",
   },
   "content_available" : true,
}
```

[The Java library](https://github.com/google/gcm) is just a sample, you can add other fields to it. For example, in the [Message.java](https://github.com/google/gcm/blob/master/client-libraries/java/rest-client/src/com/google/android/gcm/server/Message.java) class, you can add two private variables, one is `private final Boolean contentAvailable`, another one is `private final Map<String, String> notification`.

You can try a HTTP request in your terminal by doing `curl -i -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Authorization:key=API_KEY"  -X POST -d '{"to":"REGISTRATION_TOKEN", "notificaiton":{"sound":"default", "badge":"1", "title": "default", "body":"test",},"content_available":true}' https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send`, or try it in [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/).

**Edited:**

If your application was terminated, and you want to the push notifications to be shown in your device, you can set a [high priority](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options?hl=en#setting-the-priority-of-a-message) in your HTTP request body (*beware that setting your messages to high priority contributes more to battery drain compared to normal priority messages*).

Sample HTTP request:

```
{
   "to" : "REGISTRATION_TOKEN",
    "notification" : {
     "sound" : "default",
     "badge" : "1",
     "title" : "default",
     "body"  : "Test",
   },
   "content_available" : true,
   "priority" : "normal",
 }
```

Comment: Is there any other way to proceed? Because the Java library I use (https://github.com/google/gcm) doesn't seem to feature the content_available field or the notification payload. I will edit my answer to put a code snippet of the message I send using that library.

Comment: Thanks for the idea of Postman. I tried to use your POST request but it is really weird: if I send the request, I get an "error: notRegistered" and the app cannot receive notifications anymore (even the ones I did receive in the foreground). I have to generate a new GCM token to make it work again and as soon as I use the POST request it happens again. Do you know why?

Comment: `registration token` is supposed to be unique per device per app per installation, if your app was deleted before, and was reinstalled again, it will generate a new token, if you call the `GGLInstanceID` method. If you store the old `registration token` in your server or local database, you should update it to a new one once your app is reinstalled.

Comment: Yes I do register the good token on my server. What is bothering me is that the POST request acts like it unregisters the app from GCM.

Comment: So do you received push notification when your app is in background? What you meant by unregisters your app from GCM? You can only unregister your app, if you delete your app, or call [deleteTokenWithAuthorizedEntity](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/ios/api/interface_g_g_l_instance_i_d.html#a4f8fde7337f07269f0f6183d191603c3)

Comment: The answer I get from GCM when I send the POST request to send the GCM message contains the error "notRegistered" and then I cannot receive messages anymore. What is strange is that I didn't have that issue when I was sending messages with the java library. (except, of course, the fact that I don't receive notifications when the app is in background)

Comment: Please screenshot or paste the POST request you use from Postman in your question.

Comment: that might be an intermittent error from GCM, but you need to make sure to replace the value of `to` to a new `registration token` in the HTTP request body every time you get a new token. I got the `notRegistered` error, if I call the `deleteTokenWithAuthorizedEntity` manually before I call `tokenWithAuthorizedEntity`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I really don't get what the problem is,  I retried the POST request three times in a row and I got a success response but my device received nothing, then an "Internal Server Error" and finally the "notRegisteredError".

Comment: But did you see the `NSLog(@"Notification received: %@", userInfo);` get printed? It wont be able to show a `UIAlertView` if your app is in background.

Comment: I finally receive messages in background by changing "NO" to "YES" in `self.registrationOptions = @{kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption:deviceToken, kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:@NO};`. Now I just have to make the changes you suggest in the java sample but the problem is I only have a jar file so I can't access the `Message` class and modify it. How could I perform that please?

Comment: I accepted your answer, thanks again. With Postman by putting both data and notification payloads I got exactly what I want. However to send the request I modified my app server code and edited my question to show you because it doesn't work. Could you tell me what is wrong with it?

Comment: Have you resolve your issue? What is the problem you are having now with your server side code? I think it will be better if you post a new question, so other people can look into it too.

Comment: @Gannicus i'm having the same problem as you, when i send the "notification" to the payload i get unregistered and i stop getting messages. I have in my registrationOption false in  kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption so dont know whats going on.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, could not receive topic notification when app was killed, this POST is working now, I had to add priority hight.

```
   {
   "to" : "/topics/offers",
   "notification" : {
     "sound" : "default",
     "badge" : "1",
     "body" : "Text",
   },
     "priority" : "high",   
}
```