# Topic push notification in the background for iOS app

Tags: ios, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I was trying to implement GCM in iOS app. I encountered problem when I wanted to send topic specific messages. It's working without problem when app is in foreground but I'm not able to receive any messages while app is in the background. Is there any specific setting or GCM message content that need to be used to make it possible? Is the possibility to send push notification to all app users that will receive notification even if application will be in the background?

Comment: It is possible that in your HTTP request body, you didnt set the `content_available` to `true`. You can see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32147010/4195406) for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need to send a user-visible [notification](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages), or use `content_available`, as ztan pointed out.