# How to send push notification via GCM to iOS device?

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have to catch up notification from GCM.
I don't receive any notification when my app is in background mode. But I can see them when it is in foreground.

for test functionality of GCM i use it:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: key= KKKKKKKKKKKK" -H "Content-Type:    application/json" -d '{"to":"XXXXXXXXX","data":{"message": "It is special push notification for test!!!"}}' https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send
```

I see this message (if app is active).
but when I use it:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: key= KKKKKKKKKKK" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"to":"XXXXXXXX","data":{"message": "It is special push notification for test!!!"},"notification":{"body":"great match!","title":"Portugal vs. Denmark","icon":"myicon"}}' https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send
```

in this case I don't see message.

**Do you know how to send notification via GCM which will show when the app is turned off?**

P.S. It looks like GCM does not work with APNs.

Comment: Your app wont be able to receive push notification if it is completely terminated. But if it is in the background, you can set the `content_available` to `true`, you can check [this StackOverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32134815/google-cloud-messaging-dont-receive-alerts-when-ios-app-is-in-background/32147010#32147010) for more details.

Comment: Hi guys, I am receiving push notifications when app is on background mode. But when app is turned off i cant receive any notification from GCM! did anybody solve the problem?

Comment: @Yestay Muratov: did you read & try my answer ;) Maybe you want to check question on http://stackoverflow.com/a/34712161/517134

Answer (score 1):

You need to send priority parameter as high to notify ios devices.

The description for proirity is;

> Sets the priority of the message. Valid values are "normal" and
>   "high." On iOS, these correspond to APNs priority 5 and 10.
>
> By default, messages are sent with normal priority. Normal priority
>   optimizes the client app's battery consumption, and should be used
>   unless immediate delivery is required. For messages with normal
>   priority, the app may receive the message with unspecified delay.
>
> When a message is sent with high priority, it is sent immediately, and
>   the app can wake a sleeping device and open a network connection to
>   your server.

But I think it is not an enough description.

I created a [library](https://github.com/ykartal/GCMNotifier) for Java and its test cases notify apple devices when they are foreground, background or not running.