# ios didreceiveremotenotification is never called when the app is swiped killed

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging

My app is able to capture notification in foreground, background as well as in swiped-killed( i.e it shows the icon and the message on notification bar as it should).

But only if the app is swiped killed the app do receives the notification but it is unable to process or even get the data passed from server.

We're using gcm push notification for ios.

Comment: Are you sending content_available = true and priority= high parameters. And also send notification parameter although sending data parameter.

Maybe
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34704736/gcm-notifications-not-receiving-when-app-is-in-background-mode-in-ios is helpful for you

Comment: Yes, we are using all the three parameters.

Comment: @ShakilAbbas did u get solution?