# GCM iOS Production not receiving notifications

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

So, I have a problem with GCM. I have uploaded .p12 development and production APNS certificates to Google Console (I've checked, they are the same name, bundle identifier). I have my development and production provision profile all set up. I have `aps-environment` in my production profile and I am able to upload normally to iTunes Connect. I am using:

```
    _registrationOptions = @{kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption:deviceToken,
                    kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:@NO};
```

for production. It is set to NO. For my development it is set to YES. I've checked, I am getting device token, and it is sent to my server.

Push notifications are just not working in Production environment. They only work in Development environment. Do you have any idea what's the cause?

Comment: Did you try production version on another device instead your development device.

Comment: I have the same problem and it's frustrating me ! I did everything in the doc, and it working like a charm in development environment. but once I moved to the production environment i keep getting ...."error": "NotRegistered"... ! and there's no other solution or explanation beside "_registrationOptions = @{kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption:deviceToken,
                    kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:@NO};"

Comment: @YusufKARTAL you think that it may be the problem ? i remember that using urban airship if you wanted to have the production environment working in the same device you used to test with you need to remove your device id from the list of development ... ? is there a way to test ? to remove to unregister maybe ?

Comment: @Soufiane.ess yes, we faced the same scenario and noticed that the device which have development provisioning profile does not recieve production push messages, maybe sending via testflight solve the problem. We solved this problem with testing on another test device which does not have provisioning profile

Comment: @YusufKARTAL hmm or we can maybe only remove the development provisioning profil from the device ?

Comment: @YusufKARTAL but in general this is wearied with GCM. when i get to the com.google.iid-tokens of the installed app i notice that the |O|GMSInstanceIDApnsTokenKey|prod is in a wrong format ... why I don't know it's a registration id generated by gcm ^^'. do you know how can we get in touch with google gcm team just to understand ? or a reason for the wrong format registration key ?

Comment: @Soufiane.ess I don't try to remove provisioning profile. Maybe GCM sending all messages via development p12 file (did you remember you uploaded p12 files to GCM to send notifications maybe the uploaded p12 files must be checked).

Comment: @Soufiane.ess Incidentally, I also noticed that if you sent a wrong format of JSON message to GCM for a device token, next message sent to this device token will receive NotRegistered. So maybe you want to check your sending messages format as (for PHP) http://stackoverflow.com/a/34712161/517134 or (for Java) using https://github.com/ykartal/GCMNotifier

Comment: @YusufKARTAL by the way thanks for the reply, actually we are using node.js. but for testing purpose i'm using postman and using google api [link]https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send with this data format `{ "to" : "mjB2twpzbRo:APA91bGN8....",
"content_available" : true, 
"priority":"high"
"notification" : { "body" : "great match!", "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark" } }` also setting authorization header and format

Comment: PS : I renewed p12 file to be sure ... and still got nothing. I'll try to restart everything and let you know if I come up with something. thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103396/discussion-between-yusuf-kartal-and-soufiane-ess).

Comment: I've still not solved this problem. I have tested on TestFlight only device, without development provisioning profile, nothing. I have noticed one more thing. GCM works, in most of the time, ok with iOS 8 devices. But on iOS 9 it just does not work.

Comment: @Flipper Hi, you may need to renew your push certifications there was a problem with the Apple world wide Developer relations certification authority certificates and this may affect push notifications certifs. i'm uploading actually to test flight for testing. i'll let you know.

Comment: @Flipper I don't know but it worked for us. If you don't receive notifications in production environment you should check you push certifs

Comment: @Soufiane.ess Yes, that was the answer, I've revoked everything. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Set `"priority": "high"`

```
{
      "to": "gcm_device_token",
      "priority": "high",
      "content_available": false,
      "notification": {
        "sound": "default",
        "badge": "1",
        "title": "Push Title",
        "body": "Push Body"
      }
    }
```

Here's the code to use for production environment :

```
_registrationOptions = @{kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption:deviceToken,
                         kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:@NO};
```

Here's the code to use for development environment :

```
_registrationOptions = @{kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption:deviceToken,
                         kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:@YES};
```

Comment: very helpful! Thanks @Ahmed

Comment: @PhilipSopher Thanks a lot