# gcm push notification: first success, then not registered in IOS

Tags: php, ios, swift, google-cloud-messaging

After all passages for receive the notification with google cloud messaging in IOS but i have this problem:
i send the post in php for the notification with server key and device's token, at first time the response is "success" but not receive nothing on device, at the second time, and subsequent times, the response is "notRegistered". I repeat all passages: create new key in keychain, load in provisioning profile, download the .cer, install in keychain, export .p12 and insert the certificates on google platform for "GoogleService-Info.plist" and reload the device's regId at php, but the response is always this. Help me please.

This is my php :

```
    $apiKey = "server key";
    $regId = 'registration token';
    $url = 'https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
    $post = '{"to" : "' . $regId . '", "content_available" : true, "priority" : "high", "notification":  {"title" : "test", "body" : "test"}}';

    $headers = array(
            "Authorization:key=$apiKey",
            'Content-Type:application/json'
            );

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ( curl_errno( $ch ) )
{
    echo 'GCM error: ' . curl_error( $ch );
}
curl_close( $ch );
    echo $result;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Op's own answer, removed from the edited question:

The problem was the old account without the new provisioning profile, go to : XCode Accounts -> Apple IDs and view details -> Download All. For be sure go to : Targets -> project name -> Build Settings -> search "Provisioning Profile" -> change automatic and select your provisioning profile in use for certificates. The mystery is the xcode's reason don't warning me don't find the correct Provisioning Profile (different bundle id).

Answer (score 1):

My five cents
In case you are having "notRegistered" error only when app is in production that was my mistake: I missed the that in the registration options provided in GCM:

```
[[GGLInstanceID sharedInstance] tokenWithAuthorizedEntity:_gcmSenderID
                                                    scope:kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM
                                                  options:_registrationOptions
                                                  handler:self.registrationHandler];
```

There is an option **kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption** which should be set to **NO** in case of **production**

Hope it helps!

Comment: This is the answer! Wow... I've been trying to figure this out for days.

Answer (score 0):

Some week ago, we also got NotRegistered error on second message send attempt. But For my experience, problem is not on ios side. The problem is on sent message parameters.

Please try to send all required and optional parameters.
Maybe you want to give a try to PHP script on [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34704736/517134)

Tip: Sending parameter "content_available as true, priority as high and notification as data" may help.

Below Example Json received with success again and again by ios devices.

```
"Content-Type" is "application/json"

{
    "registration_ids":[
    "<reg_id1>",
    "<reg_id2>",
    ],
    "priority":"high",
    "content_available":true,
    "time_to_live":2419200,
    "data":{
    "message":"Test 15:46:49",
    "title":""
    },
    "notification":{
    "title":"",
    "body":"Test 15:46:49",
    "sound":"default",
    "badge":"1"
    }
 }
```

Edit 2:
Give a try that;

```
 $apiKey = "server key";
$regId = 'registration token';
    $url = 'https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
    $post = '{"to" : "' . $regId . '","priority":"high","content_available":true,"time_to_live":2419200,"data":{"message":"GCM Notifier:Message Success","title":"GCM Notifier:Title Success"},"notification":{"title":"GCM Notifier:Title Success","body":"GCM Notifier:Message Success","sound":"default","badge":"1"}}';

    $headers = array(
            "Authorization:key=$apiKey",
            'Content-Type:application/json'
            );

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ( curl_errno( $ch ) )
{
    echo 'GCM error: ' . curl_error( $ch );
}
curl_close( $ch );
    echo $result;
```

Comment: the result doesn't change

Comment: If you add your sent message's json data to your question, We may have more idea to fix the problem

Comment: Edited answer and take changes on your PHP code, could you try again.

Comment: What is the response message? still not registered?

Comment: yes, first time "success" and not receive nothing and at second time "NotRegistered". This is the first time i send notification with account with another organization's permissions and this is the first time i read this response and this is the first time the Production SSL Certificate is Apple Push Services and not APNs Distribution iOS, maybe the problem is the certificate?

Comment: I have tested your PHP code with my server key and reg_id. And there is no notification on IPAD and then I changed as above code and IPAD is notified. Maybe recreating development and production certifates may solve.