# Whats mean Response from GCM and Why is notification not working?

Tags: c#, android, google-cloud-messaging

I have some code for push notification c# to GCM. When I run code c# , GCM  response me an id like this : **id=0:145310308361%a68blablad6cf16** . But **statuscode :OK** . What is mean this id and another question: this response in the **pushnotification** function but when I run this function my device not take the notification ?.

**C# code like this:**

```
 public string SendAndroidPushNotification(string RegistrationID, string message)
{

    string GoogleAppID = "ServerId";
    var SENDER_ID = "ProjectId";
    var value = message;
    WebRequest tRequest;
    tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
    tRequest.Method = "post";
    tRequest.ContentType = " application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
    tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", GoogleAppID));

    tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", SENDER_ID));

    string postData = "collapse_key=score_update&time_to_live=108&delay_while_idle=1&data.message=" + value.ToString() + "&data.time=" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "&registration_id=" + RegistrationID + "";
    //Console.WriteLine(postData);
    Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
    tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

    Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream();
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    dataStream.Close();

    WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse();

    dataStream = tResponse.GetResponseStream();

    StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

    String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();

    HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)tResponse;
    string statusCode = httpResponse.StatusCode.ToString();

    tReader.Close();
    dataStream.Close();
    tResponse.Close();
    return sResponseFromServer;
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string device_Id = "myRegisteredId";
    string msj = "";
    msj = TextBox1.Text.ToString();
    string strResponse = SendAndroidPushNotification(device_Id, msj);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see GCM Diagnosis Tool for an application on [Google Play Developer Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/).
And you can check activity of message with this id.

[GCM Reference](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) is more helpful for your question;
Send message parameters and response message details and code descriptions are written detailed.

And maybe you want to have a look at [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34704736/517134) for success

Comment: thanks , I solved it, id=0:145310308361%a68blablad6cf16  mean successful responce.

Comment: You're welcome. You can accept true answers of your questions. 