# GCM Curl php send two push

Tags: php, curl, google-cloud-messaging

I'm implementing GCM on my website from [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/push-notifications/step-03?hl=en)

All work fine when I send a Curl query by command line on the dev windows, I see one call of the event listener.

But, when I send query by PHP, there are two call of the listener. I don't know where that from....

My PHP code :

```
<?php
//request url
$url    = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

//your api key
$apiKey = $apiKey;

//registration ids
$registrationIDs = array('fwt_qmI-Rlo:A...eencfYg2_0WU');

$fields = array('registration_ids' => $registrationIDs);

//http header
$headers = array('Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,
                 'Content-Type: application/json');

//curl connection
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
?>
```

And my JS code :

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  console.log('Push message', event);
});
```

I never realy used Curl on PHP, and maybe there are errors...

Can someone help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you write the exact output of echo $result; line?

Comment: Yes, response from GCM : {"multicast_id":5922533053428689025,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1453277704633711%02071e9af9fd7ecd"}]}. thx

Comment: It seems only one message sent to the GCM SERVER. You may try your PHP code on http://phpfiddle.org/ or may be you may want to use PHP code on http://stackoverflow.com/a/34712161/517134

Comment: Thx for reponse. I juste find the "solution". The problem come from I used the same instance of browser. When I use same bowser (in new tab or new window, no importance), I received 2 push (except in private mode). But when I use an another browser or when an other people push me, I received juste one push... I found solution when I testing PHP code on phpfiddle.org and received one push. Thx for help.

Comment: You're welcome, Maybe It is useful for others if you answer your own question and accept it. ;)