# Push Notifications and Php

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I can successfully store the registration_id. However when I am sending a message from my sample page,I get nothing.

The response I have from php is.

```
done{"multicast_id":5441272458021564268,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1454957764463721%e104448af9fd7ecd"}]}
```

As you can see the *canonical_ids* object has a zero value. I think this should have some value,indicating that my message has been send to the GCM.

Please check my **php code**

```
<?php
   include("init.php");
   $url = 'https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
    $apikey = 'AIzaSyDpdrSDJriqAsqCzB7gGURmjrZIm6q0KZM';
   $message="";
$registration_ids = array();
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
    $name = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_info where email = '".$name."'";

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        array_push($registration_ids,$row['token_id']);

    }
}

$message_send = array("Notice"=>$message);
$fields = array(
    'registration_ids' => $registration_ids,
    'data' => $message_send
);

$headers = array('Authorization: key='.$apikey,
                'Content-Type: application/json'
                );


$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode($fields));


$result = curl_exec($ch);
if($result === FALSE){
    die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
}

curl_close($ch);
echo "done".$result;

 ?>
```

I know that the push notification are run by using a Broadcast Receiver and an Intent Service.

So

```
public class MyGcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),GcmIntentService.class.getName());


    startWakefulService(context,(intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);

}
```

}

and the intent service.

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService{
public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
private static final String TAG="GcmIntentService";
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;

public GcmIntentService() {
    super("GcmIntentService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

    if(!extras.isEmpty()){
        if(GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)){
            sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
        }
    }else if(GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)){

        sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " + extras.toString());

    }else if(GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)){

        sendNotification(extras.getString("Notice"));

        Log.v(TAG,"Received " + extras.toString());
    }

    MyGcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}

private void sendNotification(String s) {
    Log.v(TAG,s);

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,
            new Intent(this,MainActivity.class),0);


    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("GCMDemo")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(s))
                .setContentText(s);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID,mBuilder.build());

}
```

}

I am not sure what is exactly is going on. The Broadcast receiver which is custom generates and action and runs an IntentService. This services get the message as an extra which is a String.

And finally here is my **manifest.xml**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="testing.theo.testpushnotifications">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<permission
    android:name="testing.theo.testpushnotifications.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="testing.theo.testpushnotifications.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:name=".AppController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".MyGcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            <category android:name="testing.theo.testpushnotifications"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".GcmIntentService"/>

    <activity android:name=".Register"></activity>

</application>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GCM Notifications not receiving when app is in background mode in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34704736/gcm-notifications-not-receiving-when-app-is-in-background-mode-in-ios)

Comment: As duplicate [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34704736/517134) use 'notification' => $message instead "Notice"=>$message

Comment: Zero for the `canonical_ids` means that none of your token values need updating. The `success` value of 1, and the presence of `message_id`, indicates all was well with your message as far as GCM was concerned.