# IOS receive push notification from google GCM when app not running in swift

Tags: php, ios, swift, swift2, google-cloud-messaging

I am using iOS 9.2 and swift 2
and I use google GCM to send notifications from php server to iOS users 
every things is ok when the app in foreground or background but when the app not running any more the notification didn't appear

this is my server side code

```
$access_key =  'access_key';
$registrationIdsIOS = ["registrationIdsIOS"] ; 

// prep the bundle
$msg = array
(
    'message'   => 'message',
    'title'     => 'title',
    'subtitle'  => 'This is a subtitle. subtitle',
    'tickerText'    => 'Ticker text here...Ticker text here...Ticker text here',
    'vibrate'   => 1,
    'sound'     => 1,
    'largeIcon' => 'large_icon',
    'smallIcon' => 'small_icon'
);
$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids'  => $registrationIdsIOS,
    'data'          => $msg,
    'content_available' => true

);

$headers = array
(
    'Authorization: key=' . $access_key,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send');
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );
echo $result;
```

and this my IOS side

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        // Configure the Google context: parses the GoogleService-Info.plist, and initializes
        // the services that have entries in the file
        var configureError:NSError?
        GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
        assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")
        gcmSenderID = GGLContext.sharedInstance().configuration.gcmSenderID

        // Register for remote notifications
        if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        } else {
            // Fallback
            let types: UIRemoteNotificationType = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
            application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types)
        }


        // [END register_for_remote_notifications]
        // [START start_gcm_service]
        let gcmConfig = GCMConfig.defaultConfig()
        gcmConfig.receiverDelegate = self
        GCMService.sharedInstance().startWithConfig(gcmConfig)
        // [END start_gcm_service]


        UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0

        if launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] != nil{

            let now = NSDate()
            let prefs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            let notification = UILocalNotification()
            notification.alertBody = "test"
            //notification.alertTitle = userInfo["title"] as? String
            notification.alertTitle = "app name"
            notification.alertAction = "open"
            notification.fireDate = now
            notification.soundName = prefs.objectForKey("ton") as? String
            notification.userInfo = ["id":"id"]
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)

        }

        return true
    }


    func application( application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken
        deviceToken: NSData ) {
            // [END receive_apns_token]
            // [START get_gcm_reg_token]
            // Create a config and set a delegate that implements the GGLInstaceIDDelegate protocol.
            let instanceIDConfig = GGLInstanceIDConfig.defaultConfig()
            instanceIDConfig.delegate = self
            // Start the GGLInstanceID shared instance with that config and request a registration
            // token to enable reception of notifications
            GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().startWithConfig(instanceIDConfig)
            registrationOptions = [kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption:deviceToken,
                kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:true]
            GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().tokenWithAuthorizedEntity(gcmSenderID,
                scope: kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM, options: registrationOptions, handler: registrationHandler)
            // [END get_gcm_reg_token]


    }


    // [START receive_apns_token_error]
    func application( application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError
        error: NSError ) {
            print("Registration for remote notification failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            // [END receive_apns_token_error]
            let userInfo = ["error": error.localizedDescription]
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(
                registrationKey, object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
    }


    func registrationHandler(registrationToken: String!, error: NSError!) {
        if (registrationToken != nil) {
            self.registrationToken = registrationToken
            print("Registration Token: \(registrationToken)")

            let prefs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

            if (prefs.objectForKey("notificationRegId") as? String) != registrationToken{

                self.sendToken(registrationToken)
                prefs.setValue(registrationToken as String, forKey: "notificationRegId")
                prefs.synchronize()
            }


            //self.subscribeToTopic()
            let userInfo = ["registrationToken": registrationToken]
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(
                self.registrationKey, object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
        } else {
            print("Registration to GCM failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            let userInfo = ["error": error.localizedDescription]
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(
                self.registrationKey, object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
        }
    }


    func sendToken(token:String){

        if token == ""{
          print("there is no token to send to server")
        }else{
           //send token to server
        }



    }


    // [START ack_message_reception]
    func application( application: UIApplication,
        didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
            print("Notification received: \(userInfo)")
            // This works only if the app started the GCM service


            let now = NSDate()
            let prefs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            let notification = UILocalNotification()
            notification.alertBody = userInfo["gcm.notification.message"] as? String
            //notification.alertTitle = userInfo["title"] as? String
            notification.alertTitle = "app name"
            notification.alertAction = "open"
            notification.fireDate = now
            notification.soundName = prefs.objectForKey("ton") as? String
            notification.userInfo = ["id":"id"]
             UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber += 1
            GCMService.sharedInstance().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo);
            // Handle the received message
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(messageKey, object: nil,
                userInfo: userInfo)
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
    }


    func application( application: UIApplication,
        didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
        fetchCompletionHandler handler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
            print("Notification received: \(userInfo)")

            // This works only if the app started the GCM service
            GCMService.sharedInstance().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo);
            // Handle the received message
            // Invoke the completion handler passing the appropriate UIBackgroundFetchResult value
            // [START_EXCLUDE]

            let now = NSDate()
            let prefs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            let notification = UILocalNotification()
            notification.alertBody = userInfo["gcm.notification.message"] as? String
            //notification.alertTitle = userInfo["title"] as? String
            notification.alertTitle = "app name"
            notification.alertAction = "open"
            notification.fireDate = now
            notification.soundName = prefs.objectForKey("ton") as? String
            notification.userInfo = ["id":"id"]
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber += 1
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(messageKey, object: nil,
                userInfo: userInfo)
            handler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NoData);
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
    }



    // [START on_token_refresh]
    func onTokenRefresh() {
        // A rotation of the registration tokens is happening, so the app needs to request a new token.
        print("The GCM registration token needs to be changed.")
        GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().tokenWithAuthorizedEntity(gcmSenderID,
            scope: kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM, options: registrationOptions, handler: registrationHandler)
    }
    // [END on_token_refresh]

    // [START upstream_callbacks]
    func willSendDataMessageWithID(messageID: String!, error: NSError!) {
        if (error != nil) {
            // Failed to send the message.
        } else {
            // Will send message, you can save the messageID to track the message
        }
    }

    func didSendDataMessageWithID(messageID: String!) {
        // Did successfully send message identified by messageID
    }
    // [END upstream_callbacks]

    func didDeleteMessagesOnServer() {
        // Some messages sent to this device were deleted on the GCM server before reception, likely
        // because the TTL expired. The client should notify the app server of this, so that the app
        // server can resend those messages.
    }



    func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
        GCMService.sharedInstance().disconnect()
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        self.connectedToGCM = false
        // [END_EXCLUDE]

    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Connect to the GCM server to receive non-APNS notifications
        GCMService.sharedInstance().connectWithHandler({
            (NSError error) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                print("Could not connect to GCM: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                self.connectedToGCM = true
                print("Connected to GCM")
                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                self.subscribeToTopic()
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }
        })

    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GCM Notifications not receiving when app is in background mode in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34704736/gcm-notifications-not-receiving-when-app-is-in-background-mode-in-ios)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Payload for iOS is bit different. The structure should be following format

```
{
  "content_available":true, 
  "to":"gcm_token_of_the_device",
  "priority":"high",
  "notification":
    {
      "body":"anything",
      "title":"any title"
    }
}
```

**Note:** Content_available should be true and priority should be high then only u recevied the notification. when your app is in closed state

Comment: thanks for your replaying , now the iPhone make notification sound but there is no notification appear

Comment: thanks it works fine after i change $msg = array
(
    'message'   => 'message',
    'title'     => 'title',
    'vibrate'   => 1,
    'sound'     => 1,
);             to         $msg = array
(
    'body'   => 'message',
    'title'     => 'title',
    'vibrate'   => 1,
    'sound'     => 1,
);