# GCM Push Notification not working on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send Push Messages from the server to my iOS device.

The application is receiving messages (only in foreground) when I am sending the following JSON message -

```
{
  "to": "<my_reg_id>",
  "data": 
    {
      "body": "Hello world",
      "title": "Title"
    }
}
```

However, when I am sending messages in the format given on [Setting up a GCM Client App on iOS](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client) (given below), I am getting `"error": "InternalServerError"` in the server response -

```
{
  "to": "<my_reg_id>",
  "content_available": true,
  "priority": "high",
  "notification":
    {
      "body": "Hello world",
      "title": "Title"
    }
}
```

Can anybody tell me what to do about this ? I really need to receive background notifications for my app.

(P.S. - I have enabled Remote Notification and Push Notification Capabilities in xCode for my app.)

Comment: From my experience, inside json, top key should be "aps" for the payload. just check apple doc...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GCM Notifications not receiving when app is in background mode in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34704736/gcm-notifications-not-receiving-when-app-is-in-background-mode-in-ios)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I used the field "aps" in the JSON payload, and also updated my certificates on the Google Developers Console.....and voila!
I am now receiving push notifications on my device.  :D
Thanks for the help everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

"Internal server error" is server side issue. Kindly restart the server and try once again.

Your json Format is correct

```
{
  "content_available":true,
  "to":"gcm_registration_token",
  "priority":"high",
  "notification":
    {
    "body":"anything",
    "title":"any title"
    }
}
```

Comment: There was no server. I am using Postman for sending messages to the device. It was the issue with using "aps" and maybe some issue with my Certificates I was using for GCM.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `true,@"content_available"` from your json.This worked for me.