# IOS GCM push notifications not working in background

Tags: php, ios, curl, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I'm working on getting background notifications to work on ios with GCM - non-background notifications are already working.
In background notifications sometimes come and sometimes not. I used 
content_available = true;
I successfully obtained a Registration Token too.

This code functional

```
$fields = array(
    'registration_ids' => $devices,
    'content_available' => true ,
    'notification' => array("title" => "title", "body"=>"body"),
    'data' => array("message"=>"hi")
);
```

but not get notification in background. can you please tell me exact reason why GCM not working in Ios when app in background ???

Comment: Have you tried to do a HTTP message sending request through Postman or curl? You can refer [this StackOverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32147010/4195406) for more details.

Comment: From php to IOS? I think the problem is on the IOS side, your send request looks ok. Perhaps catch the result and see if it really succeeds or gives an error. Not sure if you need content_available, I just tested without and my screen lights up with the notification.

Comment: So your iOS app can successfully receive push notification now? Even your app is in background?

Comment: Thanks for replies, after spending few days I got the solution, please have look below answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem !!!!!!!!                                                                    in your PHP code, you do not need to include the "registration_ids" to send a downstream message, the "registration_ids" is used to create a device group for multiple registration tokens, not to send a downstream message to your app.

Beside sending a downstream message from your PHP server, you can try to use curl to send a push notification in your terminal (You also need to make sure your app is in background but not terminated):

> curl -i -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H
>   "Authorization:key=API_KEY"  -X POST -d '{"to":"REGISTRATION_TOKEN",
>   "notificaiton":{"sound":"default", "badge":"1", "title": "default",
>   "body":"test",},"content_available":true}'
>   https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send

```
 if you are testing in development mode for ios:
```

> _registrationOptions = @{kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption:deviceToken,
>                                kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:@YES};

with this code in ios and php you can get notification in background also.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and I found that setting "priority" key solve the problem with APNs and immediately push messages.

Set the priority key in Your payload according to the docs here: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message

Here You have more info about Apple APNs priorities and its behaviour here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/APNsProviderAPI.html

So for receive the Push immediately try this payload example:

```
{
  "to": "gcm_device_token",
  "priority": "high",
  "content_available": false,
  "notification": {
    "sound": "default",
    "badge": "1",
    "title": "Push Title",
    "body": "Push Body"
  }
}
```