# Not receiving GCM notification in notification tray when app is killed

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios8, google-cloud-messaging

I am receiving GCM notifications in my iphone at top when app is active or in back ground but the problem is that when app got killed notifications will not shown at the top.

Comment: Can you post your full HTTP request body? Usually if you add a `priority` parameter in your request body, and set it to `high`, your app will be able to receive push notifications even it was killed by user. You can see [this Stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32134815/google-cloud-messaging-dont-receive-alerts-when-ios-app-is-in-background/32147010#32147010) for more details.

Comment: @ztan dear thank u so much... you made my day dear.. by adding parameter **'priority'** and set it to **high** works for me. Thanks

Comment: @ztan: Thanks, setting priority: high worked.