# Google cloud messaging not receiving notifications on iOS

Tags: ios, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I am using GCM in iOS for receiving notifications, the client app connects to GCM, receives registration token and successfully subscribe to topic but still fails to receive any notification.

The payload I am sending is

> {"to": "/topics/test", "notification": {"body" : "Test"}}

to

http://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send

the response I receive from the server is

> {   "message_id": 5517207416953280202 }

but still no notifications, can someone please point me to the right direction?

Comment: You should use `https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send` as the URL, also, if your app is in background or terminated, you need to change the HTTP request body parameters. You can read [this StackOverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32147010/4195406) for more details.

Comment: Also note that for testing purposes you may want to set priority to high, but use normal for production unless the message needs immediate user attention.