# GCM push notifications don't send to iOS

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send a notification through GCM to my app and it works perfectly as long as the app is open. If the app is in background or killed I don't receive anything until I open the app.

This problem happens only on iOS, on Android it's working as expected.

This is the JSON that is sent to GCM:

```
{
  "to": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "priority": "high",
  "content_available": true,
  "notification": {
    "sound": "default",
    "body": "asldsfsadfsadfs",
    "title": "asdfasdfasdfasdf"
  },
  "data": {
    "message": "some message"
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide us the logs?

For the meantime, you may check this stack overflow ticket which is related to your case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32134815/google-cloud-messaging-dont-receive-alerts-when-ios-app-is-in-background

Comment: I found this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14616261/receiving-push-notifications-while-in-background) which might help you.